# Font Awesome's New Roleout Old/ New Deployment

Tags: font-awesome

Apparently Font Awesome rolled out a new platform over the weekend. Which is great I like the new UI and Icons etc. My question is I've been in the middle of developing multiple Web Portals and have relied heavily on Font-Awesome... The old Icons still display but when performing a search for new icons only the new Icon format shows. For example today I wanted to add a clock icon... so doing a search on a clock the new icon is: **fas fa-clock** When I tried to add this to my project... nothing. Fortunately I was able to Google the old clock as being fa fa-clock-o.

Obviously to use the new Icons I have to add the updated links... but my question is: Will switching to the new library mean I have to rename all my currently used icons to the new names, I imagine not but just want to confirm. Also is their a search tool still available for the old icon names as I still have the old library referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FA has recently made a change of major version from FA4 to FA5. You can still use the old icons (they still look awesome ;-)), the directory has been moved to [this URL](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icons/).

If you want to upgrade your installation to V5, you'd have to update the references to the icons in one way or another (might be as easy as a regex search & replace across your source-files). There are more tips [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4).

Comment: Thank you! I did experiment somewhat referencing V5 and some icons did show... but others did not. I did some research and found they have a hybrid reference so you can essentially reference both... But I really did not want to do that. The URL to V4 Icons was perfect as I would rather not use V5 until I completely start a new project instead of the hybrid approach.